# HTML CSS Ken Burns distorted effect

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a header image ( 3279 x 710 px ) and I added a Ken Burns effect to it, but it seems like it is distorted. I made a fiddle with a test image, but i can't reproduce the distorted effect, however it has something to do with it's aspect ratio. The Image looks like it's pressed together.

Right now i tried to fix it with width set to auto and height to 100%, but I can't get it to work.

I made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k3fk8edr/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="header-wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <img src='http://eventzerz.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Test-Logo-Small-Black-transparent-1.png' class='image-kenburns'>
  <div id="header">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header-wrapper {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 6em 0 9em 0;
}

.wrapper .title {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  width: 25em;
  /*
            height: 3.25em;
*/
  height: 3.4em;
  top: -3.25em;
  line-height: 3.25em;
  margin-bottom: -3.25em;
  margin-left: -12.5em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12em 0;
}

.homepage #header {
  padding: 18em 0;
}

.image-kenburns {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: move 40s ease-in infinite;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
    -o-transform-origin: bottom left;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    -o-transform: scale(1.0);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```

EDIT: I should mention that it's fine looking on desktop, what I need is the responsive version for tablets.

Comment: You can't use `height:100%` and `width:100%` together and still keep the aspect ratio. One of these will have to be set to `auto`, because otherwise the image will fill out its parent regardless of wether the parents aspect ratio is the same as the image.

Comment: I tried that already. I have a Image with People on it, and whenever i set width or height to auto it looks like their heads are pressed together

Comment: The image in the fiddle seems to be fine when the `height` is set to auto, though. Maybe there is something missing in the Fiddle that causes this?

Comment: Exactly, thats what I meant with 'I can't reproduce ...'

I managed to solve my problem on my own, it had something to do with the size of the image itself. Little frustrating, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need your image to resize proportionally / keep the aspect ratio just add to your `.image-kenburns` class `height: auto`